# How to make a program sort ages into age groups with my program?

Tags: python, function

I made a program that would write the youngest and the oldest person in a .txt list.

Now I need to make the program sort people and ages into certain age groups.

```
 [0-6], [7-15], [16-18], [19-30], [31-50], [51-)
```

For example, the list would be:

```
Stacy 11
David 20
George 5
Wiliam 15
Annie 8
Christina 10
```

The program should open a new .txt  file looking like this:

```
0-6
Georgie 5

7-15
Annie 8
Christina 10
Stacy 11
Wiliam 15

19-30
David 20
```

etc. I think you all get what I mean.
Right now my program prints the youngest and the oldest out of the list.

Here it is:

```
def parse_info():
 info = open("info.txt", "r")
 max_age = 0
 max_name = ''
 min_age = float('inf')
 min_name = ''

 for line in info:
    m_list = line.split(" ")
    if int(m_list[1]) > max_age:
        max_age = int(m_list[1])
        max_name = m_list[0]
    elif int(m_list[1]) < min_age:
        min_age = int(m_list[1])
        min_name = m_list[0]
 info.close()
 return ((min_name,min_age),(max_name,max_age))
 #end of function
nameAge=parse_info()
f = open("output.txt","w")
f.write(nameAge[0][0]+" "+str(nameAge[0][1])+"\n")
f.write(nameAge[1][0]+" "+str(nameAge[1][1]))
```

How can I make the program print the youngest and the oldest out of the list FIRST and then after make it sort everyone into the given age groups above?

The program should write into the .txt file like this:

```
George 5
David 20

0-6
George 5

7-15
Annie 8
Christina 10
Stacy 11
Wiliam 15

19-30
David 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a dict to group and check what range the score falls into:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

# create dict with score ranges as keys
d = OrderedDict((("0-6", []), ("7-15", []), ("16-18", []), ("19-30", [])))

with open("match.txt") as f, open("grouped.txt", "w") as out:
    wr, read = csv.writer(out,delimiter=" "), csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")
    mn, mx = float("inf"), float("-inf")
    highest, lowest = None, None
    for row in read:
        name, score = row
        score = int(score)
        if 0 <= score < 7:
            d["0-6"].append((name, score))
        elif 7 <= score < 16:
            d["7-15"].append((name, score))
        elif 16 <= score < 19:
            d["16-18"].append((name, score))
        elif 19 <= score <= 30:
            d["19-30"].append((name, score))
        if score < mn:
            mn = score
            lowest = (name, score)
        if score > mx:
            mx = score
            highest = (name, score)

    for k, v in d.items():
        wr.writerow([k])
        wr.writerows(v)

    print(d)

{'16-18': [], '0-6': [('George', 5)], '19-30': [('David', 20)], '7-15': [('Stacy', 11), ('Wiliam', 15), ('Annie', 8), ('Christina', 10)]}

print("Highest scorer was {} with a score of {}.".format(*highest))
print("Lowest scorer was {} with a score of {}.".format(*lowest))

Highest scorer was David with a score of 20.
Lowest scorer was George with a score of 5.
```

The [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) will keep order so we just need to iterate over the dict items writing the `key` which is the group range and the list of tuples which are all the names and scores that fall into the range. The csv.reader with the `delimiter` set to `" "` will do the splitting for us so we just need to cast the score to int and check which range it falls in .

Answer (score 0):

some pseudocode:

to append people to subgroups:

```
a_list = []
```

create a group

```
>>> a=range(19,31)
>>> a
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]

for name, age in people:
    if age in int(a):
        a_list.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my silly attempt:

```
def parse_info(filename):
    max_age = 0
    max_name = ''
    min_age = float('inf')
    min_name = ''

    list_of_0_6 = []
    list_of_7_15 = []
    list_of_16_30 = []

    with open(filename, 'r') as info:
        lines = info.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        name, age = line.split()
        age = int(age)
        if age < min_age:
            min_age = age
            min_name = name
        if age > max_age:
            max_age = age
            max_name = name
        if age < 7:
            list_of_0_6.append(line)
        elif age < 16:
            list_of_7_15.append(line)
        else:
            list_of_16_30.append(line)
    return [min_name, str(min_age), max_name, str(max_age), list_of_0_6, list_of_7_15, list_of_16_30]

def writefile(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + '\n')
        outputfile.write(data[2] + ' ' + data[3] + '\n')
        outputfile.write('\n0-6\n')
        for entry in data[4]:
            outputfile.write(entry + '\n')
        outputfile.write('\n7-15\n')
        for entry in data[5]:
            outputfile.write(entry + '\n')
        outputfile.write('\n16-30\n')
        for entry in data[6]:
            outputfile.write(entry + '\n')

my_data = parse_info('info.txt')
writefile(my_data, 'output.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the groups are mutually exclusive, have a certain ordening and you know how to load the file in a propper format for python to understand, how about sorting on age, and then splitting on the first occurence of a new group?

In terms of performance, this will be `n*log(n)` instead of the `n*number_of_groups` solution provided by most of the other answers.

Comment: This is completely wrong. If you have a `log(n)` sort algorithm you should share it with the  world. Also where are the quadratic solutions?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and I assume you're going to tell me why?

Comment: You realise the sorting is (n log n) and my solution is 0(n)?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I do, It was a typo. Yours is `n*number_of_groups` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a good approach to sort the list first, and than use some helper function to calculate the people in an certain age intervall.

```
def read_info():
    """Read info file"""
    with open("info.txt", "r") as f:
        name, age = [], []
        for line in f.readlines():
            n, a  = line.strip().split(' ')
            name.append(n)
            age.append(int(a))
    return name, age

def sort_info_by_age(name, age):
    """Sort arrays by age so that youngest member is at first place"""
    sorted_ids = sorted(range(len(age)), key=lambda k: float(age[k]))
    new_name = [name[i] for i in sorted_ids ]
    new_age = [age[i] for i in sorted_ids ]
    return new_name, new_age

def get_ids_for_age_intervall(start_age, end_age, ages):
    """get indexes for members in a given age intervall"""
    ids = []
    for i, age in  enumerate(ages):
        if (start_age<=age) and (age<=end_age):
            ids.append(i)
    return ids

name, age = read_info()
name, age = sort_info_by_age(name, age)

groups = [(0,6), (7,15), (16, 18), (19, 30), (31, 50)]

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    #output younges  and oldest member
    f.write("%s %i\n" % (name[0], age[0]))
    f.write("%s %i\n" % (name[-1], age[-1]))

    #go trough age groups and write to file
    for start_age, end_age in groups:
        ids = get_ids_for_age_intervall(start_age, end_age, age)
        if ids:
            f.write("\n%i-%i\n" % (start_age, end_age))
            for i in ids:
                f.write("%s %i\n" % (name[i], age[i]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def parse_info(filepath):
    people_list = []
    groups = {"0-6": [], "7-15": [], "19-30": []}
    with open(filepath, 'r') as info:
        for line in info:
            people_list.append({"name": line.split(" ")[0], "age": line.split(" ")[1]})
        people_list = sorted(people_list, key=lambda k: k['age'])
        youngest = people_list[0]
        oldest = people_list[-1]
        for person in people_list:
            if 0 <= person['age'] < 7:    
                groups['0-6'].append(person)
            elif 7 <= person['age'] < 16:
                groups['7-15'].append(person)
            elif 19 <= person['age'] <= 30:
                groups['19-30'].append(person)

    return youngest, oldest, groups


youngest, oldest, groups = parse_info('info.txt')

with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(youngest["name"] + " " + each["age"] + "\n")
    output.write(oldest["name"] + " " + each["age"] + "\n")
    output.write("\n")

    for key, value in groups.iteritems():
        output.write(key + "\n")
        for each in value:
            output.write(each["name"] + " " + each["age"] + "\n")
        output.write("\n")
```